# Using style of EXT JS buttons for basic HTML button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, extjs

I'm using an HTML basic button in an EXT JS application.
For a specefic need, i was forced to use an HTML basic button. My problem is that i want to use the same style of EXTJS button (The component Ext.button.Button with all 'special' style events like : on click, on hover ...)
Is there any way to do it like this : tired some think like :

```
<input type="button" class="myEXTJSButtonStyle" value="Chargement" id="id"/>
```

Comment: just add what are the classes are used in extjs button.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Chrome, right click thee ExtJS button and select Inspect Element. From there you will see all the styles that had been applied to it. You can then copy them to your own stylesheet.

Comment: I've tried this, and i found that the used style is : x-btn-icon-el.
Unfortunately when i apply it to my button, the button is magically disapered :)
I think because by button is inside a grid.Panel component may be ..

Comment: Copy all the styles specified by that class into your class **myEXTJSButtonStyle**

Comment: Not only that. Be sure to copy not only the styles specified by x-btn-icon-el. To be sure copy all non-strikethroughed styles like **.x-btn-button**.

Comment: Thanks Justin, I add that using FireBug of firefox is better than chrome in my opinion.